# In rails, how to add ruby syntax to a string in link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following link_to

```
= link_to 'Get Driving Directions!', 'http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=starting&daddr=ending&hl=en'
```

I want to replace the **starting** and **ending** with ruby syntax, **location.start** and **location.end**

I've tried

```
= link_to 'Get Driving Directions!', 'http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=' + location.start+ '&daddr=' + location.end + '&hl=en'
```

but that does not seem to work. What is the best way to do this?

Edit: After playing around, it appears that although **location.start** and **location.end** are strings in the database, they are not when I try to add them on to other strings. In order to do so, Im must explicitly specify **.to_string** to both **location.start** and **location.end**

However, when I do this, the strings no longer appears on the show page. What is going on here?

Comment: That should work fine; what error do you get? Or what's the resulting url? You could also try string interpolation -  `"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=#{location.start}&daddr=#{location.end}&hl=en"`

Comment: The error I'm getting is "no implicit conversion of nil into String". I tried string interpolation, but for some reason that simply replaces starting to #{location.start}, and not the actual start string

Comment: "no implicit conversion of nil into String" might occur because either location.start or location.end is nil. Try this in console 'str' + nil same error will be returned. Check location.start.nil? and location.end.nil? before using the link

Comment: if location.read_attribute(:start) shows your string but location.start doesn't then something is overwriting the accessor generated by activerecord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting "no implicit conversion of nil into String" error, it means that your location.start or location.end is nil. So you should add a conditional check:

```
- if location.start.present? & location.end.present?
   = link_to 'Get Driving Directions!', 'http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=' + location.start+ '&daddr=' + location.end + '&hl=en'
- elsif !location.start.present? & location.end.present?
   = link_to 'Get Driving Directions!', 'http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=defaultstart' + '&daddr=' + location.end + '&hl=en'
- else
   = link_to 'Get Driving Directions!', 'http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=defaultstart&daddr=defaultend&hl=en'
```

Where defaultstart and defaultend can be replaced by default values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string interpolation:

```
= link_to 'Get Driving Directions!', "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=#{location.start}&daddr=#{location.end}&hl=en"
```

Note that I've used `"` (quotes) instead of `'` (single quotes) when using string interpolation otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_params` method.

```
params = {"saddr" => "starting", "daddr" => "ending", "hl" => "en"}.to_param
=> "daddr=ending&hl=en&saddr=starting"

url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?' + params
=> "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=ending&hl=en&saddr=starting"
```

or use [uri](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

```
require 'uri'
uri = URI.parse('http://maps.google.com/maps')
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form("saddr" => "starting", "daddr" => "ending", "hl" => "en")
#uri.query = URI.encode_www_form("saddr" => "#{location.start}", "daddr" => "#{location.end}", "hl" => "en")
=> "saddr=starting&daddr=ending&hl=en"

uri.to_s
=> "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=starting&daddr=ending&hl=en"
```